# Passing a shared_ptr through a C interface that takes void *

Tags: c++, sdl, shared-ptr

I have a C++ project that uses [SDL](http://libsdl.org/), in particular SDL Events.  I would like to use the event system for incoming network messages just as it is used for UI events.  I can define a new event type and attach some arbitrary data (see [this example](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UserEvent#Code_Examples)).  This is what I would do if I was using ordinary pointers:

```
Uint32 message_event_type = SDL_RegisterEvents(1);

/* In the main event loop */
while (SDL_Poll(&evt)) {
    if (evt.type == message_event_type) {
         Message *msg = evt.user.data1;
         handle_message(msg);
    }
}

/* Networking code, possibly in another thread */
Message *msg = read_message_from_network();
SDL_Event evt;
evt.type = message_event_type;
evt.user.data1 = msg;
SDL_PostEvent(evt);
```

Instead, I've been using `shared_ptr<Message>` up to now.  Messages are read-only objects once constructed, and might be used in lots of places while being handled, so I thought to use shared_ptr for them.

I would like to use a shared_ptr to the message in the network side, and also on the event handling side.  If I do this:

```
// in networking code:
shared_ptr<Message> msg = ...
evt.user.data1 = msg.get();

// later, in event handling:
shared_ptr<Message> msg(evt.user.data1);
```

then there are two independent shared_ptrs and either one could delete the Message object while the either is still using it.  I would need to somehow pass the shared_ptr through the SDL_UserEvent struct, which only has a couple of `void *` and int fields.

**Additional.** Note that `SDL_PostEvent` returns immediately; the event itself is put on a queue.  The event may be popped from the queue by the handler well after a shared_ptr to the message has gone out of scope in the networking code.  So I can't pass the address of a local shared_ptr to copy from.  By the time the copying occurs, it's likely to no longer be valid.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and knows of a nice solution?

Comment: Related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482806/manually-incrementing-and-decrementing-a-boostshared-ptr

Comment: Why shared_ptr, why not let another class create and delete them and pass them as reference if needed?

Comment: Pass a pointer to the `shared_ptr`, and make a value copy of it in the receiving function. E.g. `evt.user.data1 = &msg;` and `shared_ptr<Message> msg = *reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<Message>*>(evt.user.data1);`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: looks like a good solution for when the copy can be made before the event posting function returns.  But it can't.  The event has to live on a queue, and when it gets popped the original shared_ptr to it may well have gone.

Comment: @Edmund: It sounds like you need to roll your own reference counting system rather than relying on `shared_ptr` to me (although if the ref count can be manually incremented as @EyasSH suggests below then  shared_from_this could be an option)

Answer (score 6):

Allocate a pointer to the shared ptr with *new*.  This calls the constructor (incrementing the reference count), but the corresponding destructor is not called so the shared_ptr will never destruct it's shared memory.

Then in the corresponding handler, just destroy the object after copying the shared_ptr bringing its reference count back to normal.

This is identical to how you'd pass any other non-primitive type through a message queue.

```
typedef shared_ptr<Message> MessagePtr;

Uint32 message_event_type = SDL_RegisterEvents(1);

/* In the main event loop */
while (SDL_Poll(&evt)) {
    if (evt.type == message_event_type) {
         // Might need to cast data1 to (shared_ptr<Message> *)
         unique_ptr<MessagePtr> data (evt.user.data1);
         MessagePtr msg = *data;
         handle_message(msg);
    }
}

/* Networking code, possibly in another thread */
MessagePtr msg = read_message_from_network();
SDL_Event evt;
evt.type = message_event_type;
evt.user.data1 = new MessagePtr (msg); 
SDL_PostEvent(evt);
```

> Messages are read-only objects once constructed

I just want to point out, this is good and even necessary for the multithreading to be safe.  You might want to use `shared_ptr<const Message>`

Comment: I've been trying to figure out  how this works. What I don't  understand is how the shared_ptr object that gets allocated with 'new' ever gets deallocated?

Comment: `unique_ptr` deallocates it at the end of the if statement.  Alternatively (perhaps more clearly?) I could instead use a raw pointer and call `delete data` at the end of the if statement.  I find it's easier to write correct code relying on `unique_ptr` than `delete`.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear now. But my application requires that several entities get an opportunity to handle the same event and I don't want the payload deleted after 1st handler. If I change the `unique_ptr` to be a `shared_ptr`, will that deallocate once they're all out scope?

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you need here.  I don't think the problem's answerable without more details, probably in the form of a SO question.

In general if you want 5 entities to handle the `Message`, then you either put the `MessagePtr` in the queue once for each entity, or you have a different queue for each entity and put the `MessagePtr` in each queue.

OP's need to put a `shared_ptr` in the queue was very unusual to me, but sticking multiple copies of the `shared_ptr` in the queue is one case that justifies this choice.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like ideal place to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

```
struct Message: std::enable_shared_from_this<Message>
{
    …
};

evt.user.data1 = msg.get();

// this msg uses the same refcount as msg above
shared_ptr<Message> msg = evt.user.data1.shared_from_this();
```

Comment: This will work only with C++ 11 and up, but it is an elegant and maintainable solution.

Comment: @qexyn `std::shared_ptr` *is* C++11 and up

Comment: For some reason I was thinking boost::shared_ptr.  Actually the OP does not specify namespace, but probably is std, in which case your C++11 solution is perfectly suited.

Comment: You probably also want to manually increment the reference count when passing to C-land and decrementing it on the way out. I think this is possible in shared_ptr when used as an intrusive pointer. Certainly possible in boost intrusive pointers.

Comment: Ok finally figured out how this works.  What stops the message from being destroyed when the first `msg` pointer goes out of scope after putting it on the queue?

Comment: @Edmund Nothing. If you need that, you need to pass instance of `shared_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of another potential technique: using placement new to store the `shared_ptr` in the same space as the C struct:

```
SDL_Event evt;
evt.type = event_type;
// create new shared_ptr, in the same memory as evt.user.code
new (&evt.user.code) shared_ptr<Message>(msg);
SDL_PushEvent(&evt);
```

SDL then copies the event around as a C object, until later code extracts the message from the event:

```
shared_ptr<Message> get_message(SDL_Event& evt) {
    // copy shared_ptr out of evt
    shared_ptr<Message> msg = *reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<Message> *>(&evt.user.code);
    // destroy shared_ptr inside the event struct
    (reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<Message> *>(&evt.user.code))->~shared_ptr();
    return msg;
}
```

There are several fields inside the event struct that should be enough space for the shared_ptr (see https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/include/SDL_events.h#L485).

I'm aware that this is a bit hacky.  I'd appreciate some sanity checking of the technique.