# C++ safely deleting event object payload with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, events, smart-pointers

I need to create an `Event` object to be dispatched by an event listener system. The `Event` needs to have following properties:

1. `Event` can potentially be handled by 0..n listener objects.
2. `Event` contains a void pointer which can point to an arbitrary object (payload) (unknown type at build time). Event listener will convert to appropriate type depending on `Event`'s name.
3. Need the payload object to be (automatically) deleted once the event has been dispatched to interested parties. Original event raiser cannot deallocate as event goes into an asvnc queue.
4. Assume listeners can make shallow copy of payload when event is processed.

I have implemented the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064361/488802), but AFAIK this causes the payload to be deallocated (via the `unique_ptr`) after the first event handler.

In the code below, 'setData' attempts to take the payload object (`dataObject`), and to convert it into a `shared_ptr` to be carried by `void* data`. `getData` does the "reverse":

```
class Event {

public:
std::string name;

Event(std::string n = "Unknown", void* d = nullptr) :name(n), data(d) {}

template<class T>  void setData(const T dataObject)
{
    //Create a new object to store the data, pointed to by smart pointer
    std::shared_ptr<T> object_ptr(new T);
    //clone the data into the new object
    *object_ptr = dataObject;

    //data will point to the shared_pointer
    data= new std::shared_ptr<T>(object_ptr);
}


//reverse of setData.
template<class T>  T getData() const
{
    std::unique_ptr<
        std::shared_ptr<T>
        > data_ptr((std::shared_ptr<T>*) data);
    std::shared_ptr<T> object_ptr = *data_ptr;

    return *object_ptr;
}

private:
    void* data;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead of `void*`. That would avoid complex memory allocation for `data`. If you can't use C++17, it's not that hard to make your own implementation from [Kevlin Henney's paper](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/ValuedConversions.pdf) (add parts missing from C++17 specification, e.g. move constructor).

Your code may become something like that:

```
class Event {

public:
std::string name;

Event() :name("Unknown") {}

template<class T>
Event(std::string n, T&& dataObject) :name(n)
{
    setData(std::forward<T>(dataObject));
}

template<class T>  void setData(T&& dataObject)
{
    using data_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    data = std::make_shared<data_t>(std::forward<T>(dataObject));
}

//reverse of setData.
template<class T>  T getData() const
{
    using data_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    return *any_cast<std::shared<data_t>>(data);
}

private:
    any data;
};
```

---

I used in my code lvalue references in the template methods to avoid overloading: template deduction allows the same method to accept named variables as well as temporary values, with or without constness. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313) for details.

[std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is used to perform [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313). Indeed, if you construct an `Event` from an lvalue like this:

```
Event e{"Hello", Foo{}};
```

Calling `setData` without perfect forwarding will pass `dataObject` as an lvalue since it is a named variable in this context:

```
setData(dataObject); // will call Foo's copy constructor
```

Perfect forwarding will pass `dataObject` as an rvalue, but **only if** it was constructed from an rvalue in the first place:

```
setData(std::forward<T>(dataObject)); // will call Foo's move constructor
```

If `dataObject` had been constructed from an lvalue, the same `std::forward` will pass it as an lvalue, and yield copy constructor invokation, as wanted:

```
Foo f{};
Event e{"Hello", f};

// ...

setData(std::forward<T>(dataObject)); // will call Foo's copy constructor
```

<kbd>[Complete demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ce3ab49e6597ee7)</kbd>

---

If you want to keep using pointers to `void`, you can embed an appriopriate deleter with the `shared_ptr`:

```
template<class T>  void setData(T&& dataObject)
{
    using data_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    data = std::shared_ptr<void>(
        new data_t{std::forward<T>(dataObject)},
        [](void* ptr)
        {
            delete static_cast<data_t*>(ptr);
        }
    );
}
```

With `data` being declared as `shared_ptr<void>`, and `getData`:

```
template<class T>  T getData() const
{
    using data_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    return *std::static_pointer_cast<data_t>(data);
}
```

Comment: Wow!, there are number of type and pointer language features here that I was not aware of, will need a day or two to digest..

Comment: Feel free to ask for explanations, so I could update my answer with more details. That would help future readers ;)

Comment: First off: why the `forward()` call in ctor, what would happen if we just called `setData(dataObject);` in the ctor?

Comment: let me get this straight; the T&& and forward<T>  construct are all about efficiently dealing with rvalues, but not needed for the core functionality.  The decay<> is to allow for arrays/fn_pointers, but again not needed in a minimal proof of concept? Just asking so I can boil this down to essentials.

Comment: this idea of embedding a deleter is also new to me , is there a name for this construct I could search.

Comment: There is no real name for this construct, that's a feature of `std::shared_ptr`. See [constructor's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (4-7). Note that the deleter is a fully accessible attribute: see [`get_deleter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter)

Comment: The T&& with templates is to avoid overloading and so code duplication. `std::forward` is for efficiency. `std::decay` is more about removing const and reference qualifiers on type T