# warning: passing argument 2 of 'g_timeout_add_seconds' removal

Tags: c++, c

I am using the 'g_timeout_add_seconds' in my code. But when i compile the following error is shown

> warning: passing argument 2 of 'g_timeout_add_seconds'
>
> g_timeout_add_seconds(1, message_cb, data);  //usage
>
> gboolean message_cb(List *data) //prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get rid of the warning - fix it.

The second parameter of `g_timeout_add_seconds` is a function pointer (`GSourceFunc`) as follows:

```
gboolean (*GSourceFunc) (gpointer user_data);
```

and `gpointer` is a pointer to `void` It's not keen on you using `List* data` instead.

Stick to the prototype and if you are passing a `List*` then cast it within the callback.

Comment: ^^ the return type is gboolean and the parameter is a pointer. what is wrong in my callback prototype?.. what is GSourceFunc. Can you give me some example

Comment: @user1410356: You are passing a `List*` not a `void*`. You need to change your callback function so that it takes a `void*` instead and then in the callback function cast from `void*` to `List*` using `reinterpret_cast`. For details on `GSourceFunc` look at (http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) and for use of `reinterpret_cast` there's some excellent answers here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast)