# reinterpret_cast and null member variables

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I'm using reinterpret_cast something like this:

```
void RunThread (void *myself)
{
   (reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(myself))->Method();
}
```

Inside Method, most of my member variables (all Handles) are null. Could this be because of reinterpret_cast since I know it does not guarantee me the same addresses? Like static_cast would. I know we should be using static_case in this instance, but this issue has got me interested now.

Comment: No. The member variables are null because you set them to null. Either that or your code sports undefined behaviour.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but just wanted to check if reinterpret_cast was capable of doing something funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `reinterpret_cast` doesn't perform any operations on source pointer, just treats its value as another pointer (or integral) type. It could give you wrong result only in case when memory pointed by`myself` does not contain `MyClass` (or binary compatible) object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast. When the top voted answer says: static_casting a pointer to and from void* preserves the address. What does he mean?

Comment: @Science_Fiction He means that `static_cast` doesn't change the *value* of pointer, but its *type* only. Let you have `MyClass* p = new MyClass();`. It will point to some allocated memory with some distinct address, say `0x100000`. `void* pv = static_cast<void*>(p);` will guarantee that 'pv' will have same value `0x100000`. Strictly formally `reinterpret_cast` doesn't guarantee so, but I don't know the platform where it works different way.

Comment: @Science_Fiction Of course, if you need only `MyClass*` -> `void*` and back casts you shal prefer `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`.