# reinterpret_cast error for enum

Tags: c++, enums, static-cast

Why i can't use reinterpret_cast operator for such a cast?

```
enum Foo { bar, baz };

void foo(Foo)
{
}

int main()
{
   // foo(0); // error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Foo'
   // foo(reinterpret_cast<Foo>(0)); // error: invalid cast from type 'int' to type 'Foo'
   foo(static_cast<Foo>(0)); 
   foo((Foo)0);
}
```

Comment: `static_cast` is the correct operation here.

Comment: Why would it be valid? What do you think reinterpret_cast is for?

Comment: I think that reinterpret_cast can be use for all types of casts, because it's force any type casts to another type with all side-effects of this conversion.

Comment: Here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I think that `reinterpret_cast` can be use for all types of casts, because it's force any type casts to another type with all side-effects of this conversion.

That is a common misconception. Conversions which can be performed with `reinterpret_cast` are listed explicitly in 5.2.10 of the standard. `int`-to-`enum` and `enum`-to-`int` conversions are not in the list:

- Pointer to integral type, so long as the integer is large enough to hold it
- `nullptr_t` to integer
- integral type or `enum` to pointer
- function pointer to another function pointer of different type
- object pointer to another object pointer of different type
- `nullptr_t` to other pointer type
- pointer-to-member of `T1` to a different pointer-to-member of `T2` in cases where both `T1` and `T2` are objects or functions

`reinterpret_cast` is typically used to tell the compiler: Hey, I know you think this region of memory is a `T`, but I'd like you to interpret it as a `U` (where `T` and `U` are unrelated types).

It is also worth noting that `reinterpret_cast` can have effects on the bits:

> **5.2.10.3**
>
> [ Note: The mapping performed by reinterpret_cast might, or might not, produce a representation dif-
>   ferent from the original value. — end note ]

The C-style cast always works, because it included `static_cast` in its attempts.

Answer (score 4):

Because regular enum underlying type is `int`, there is nothing to [*reinterpret*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). Static cast is proper conversion for this case.

Comment: @Rost that is not true.  The standard guarantees that an emum's underlying type is an *integral type*, but not necessarily an *int*.

Comment: @tenfour Well, it was added in C++11. Don't know the reason. Possibly to allow some template tricks?

Comment: If "there is nothing to reinterpret" had anything to do with correctness, then this would fail: `int x = 0; int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);`

Comment: @TravisGockel Even `reinterpret_cast<int>(x)` is allowed. So what? It just means that `reinterpret_cast` don't actually reinterpret in some cases. So, shall we name it `maybe_reinterpret_cast`? ;-)

Comment: The reason `enum`-to-`int` can't be done through `reinterpret_cast` has nothing to do with the underlying type of the `enum`. If it was `enum Foo : uint64_t { bar, baz }`, `reinterpret_cast<int>` still wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @TravisGockel Still didn't get your logic. OK, we could not `reinterpret_cast` `Foo` to `int` due to different size. But why we could not `reinterpret_cast` it to `uint64_t` or any integral of sufficient size?

Comment: Because it isn't allowed. The C++ standard does not define an `enum` to an integral type cast with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @TravisGockel I know that is not allowed, I can read standard. The question is _why_ it is not allowed. The reason?

Comment: Probably for the same reason `reinterpret_cast<long>(int(9));` isn't allowed -- it wouldn't add anything useful to the language because those types of casts are what `static_cast` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers fail to get to the point directly.
Despite being a bad use of `reinterpret_cast`, compilation fails because you can't apply `reinterpret_cast` on values directly.
You can apply it only to convert pointers of reference expressions.
(in particular, it can't convert literal constants.)

So this compiles,

```
enum Foo { bar, baz };

void foo(Foo)
{
}

int main()
{
   // foo(0);
   int zero = 0;
   foo(reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(zero)); // error: invalid cast from type 'int' to type 'Foo'
   foo(static_cast<Foo>(0)); 
   foo((Foo)0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x6MP1e5eo