# What is the named cast of old style cast: pv = (void*)ps;

Tags: c++

Code with old style cast:

```
const string *ps;  
void *pv;

pv = (void*)ps;
```

I have try three various named casts:

```
pv = static_cast<void*>(ps); //  error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const string* {aka const std::basic_string<char>*}’ to type ‘void*’

pv = const_cast<void*>(ps); // error: invalid const_cast from type ‘const string* {aka const std::basic_string<char>*}’ to type ‘void*’

pv = reinterpret_cast<void*>(ps); // error: reinterpret_cast from type ‘const string* {aka const std::basic_string<char>*}’ to type ‘void*’ casts away qualifiers
```

As you can see. Nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this special case, it's simply:

```
pv = const_cast<string*>( ps );
```

The conversion from `string*` to `void*` is implicit.  If you wanted to
make it explicit, you'd need a second, separate cast:

```
pv = static_cast<void*>( const_cast<string*>( ps ) );
```

or

```
pv = const_cast<void*>( static_cast<void const*>( ps ) );
```

I don't think making it explicit is particularly necessary, however; the
fact that you're using a `void*` already says that there will be
conversions.

Answer (score 10):

You should `const_cast`, but to the right type. The cast from `string*` to `void*` will then happen automatically.

```
pv = const_cast<string*>(ps);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have first to remove the const-ness and then to static_cast:

```
pv = static_cast<void*>(const_cast<string*>(ps));
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a `const_cast`, since conversions to (but not from) `void*` happen automatically (to convert from void, use `static_cast`):

```
pv = const_cast<string*>(ps);
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try - I guess you 2 casts - this should not be used because of the link posted below.

```
pv = reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<string*>(ps));
```

the only safe way according to C++03 seems to be to use the static_cast to cast from/to void*

```
pv = static_cast<void*>(const_cast<string*>(ps));
```

I would not use the implicit cast as it hides the cast.
But your cast looks like a bad idea - what is the context of this?

---

I just found [when to use reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast) and now I see why the static_cast is better. Still I don't like it because it somewhat hides (in my opinion) the dangerous part of casting to void. In a review it is easy to simply search for all reinterpret_casts and review the potential dangerous places.

Comment: The reinterpret cast is not necessary, and potentially dangerous. Pointers automatically convert to void pointers, so only the const is needed.