# Is it unsafe to mix static and reinterpret cast when casting to and back from void*?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

Simply: If i `static_cast` a type `X*` to `void*`, is it always safe to `reinterpret_cast` it back to X*?

I am unable to produce any case where this fails for example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct a
{
    int* m_array;
};

int main()
{
    bool fail = false;

    for(int i = 0; ++i < 5000;)
    {
        a* pA = new a;
        pA->m_array = new int [i+1]; // A new size of data everytime
        pA->m_array[i] = 10;

        void* pvA = static_cast<void*>(pA);
        pA = reinterpret_cast<a*>(pvA);

        if(pA->m_array[i] != 10)
        {
            fail = true;
            break;
        }

        delete []pA->m_array;
        delete pA;
    }

        if(fail)
            std::cout<<"FAILED!!";
        else
            std::cout<<"Never failed :/";
}
```

[Link to compiled example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=afb09f0c08b672521eb2aa99a04cca24-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59)

Gives the result "Never failed :/" in both debug and release mode with vs 2012. However this is most likely undefined behavior. Right?

Comment: This is well-defined behaviour, that is exactly what `reinterpret_cast` is for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/573345/726361 However you can use `static_cast` to cast from `void*`.

Comment: I'd say it's well defined, but can't back it up :(

Comment: @SethCarnegie The answer you link to contradicts your comment, unless I'm misreading.

Comment: @SethCarnegie He never speaks about mixing the casts as in this case.

Comment: @hvd how so? @ David it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That answer says the value of `b = reinterpret_cast<void*>(a)` is unspecified (implying it may be different from `static_cast<void*>(a)`), and you need `c = reinterpret_cast<int*>(b)` to convert it back, you cannot convert it back with `static_cast<int*>(b)`. (Actually, this question asks about mixing the two casts the other way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well-defined. As per ISO/IEC 14882:2011 [expr.reinterpret.cast]§7 (emphasis mine):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to *cv* T2”, the result is **static_cast<cv
>   T2*>(static_cast<*cv* void*>(v))** if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout
>   types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than
>   those of T1, **or if either type is void.**

Comment: That text has changed in C++11, though. I wonder if it was also well-defined earlier?

Comment: I like to state the version of the standard when I quote from it. That way if you are not using the latest a quick check is easy.