# What is the difference between '*(<type> *) &x' and 'x'?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, memory-address

What is the difference between

```
int i = 123;
int k;
k = *(int *) &i;
cout << k << endl; //Output: 123
```

And

```
int i = 123;
int k;
k = i;
cout << k << endl; //Output: 123
```

Both of them give same output but is there any difference?

(I found first snippet in the Quake3 code of Fast Inverse Square Root)

Comment: Are you sure that's equivalent to the snippet of code that you saw?  Most likely it involved casting a pointer of one type to a different type.

Comment: In the fast inverse sqrt snippet, like in any other instance of this (excluding cargo cult -- it's depressing that this has to be added) the types of `i` and `k` are different.

Comment: I bet the first snippet is not like that, but `float i = 1.23;` or something like that, in which case it's a "type punning cast" - converting one type to another. In C++ it would be better to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: If you check the code closer, you will see that the `i` in the q3 algorithm is of type `long` but it's casted to a `float`, so it's not quite the same.

Comment: Note that I removed the `C` tag, because this code is C++. Type casting in C behaves differently than in C++.

Comment: So *(int *) &i; this is a hack that allowes using reinterpret casting in C ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Q3:

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the fuck?
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

As I understand, you are interested in the following line:

```
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;
```

The `y` is a `float`, and the `i` is an `long`. Thus it is the **reinterpretation** of the floating point bit pattern as integer bit pattern.

Comment: The algorithm of the code seems to be [Fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: @User1 in Wiki it is mentioned that it is taken from Q3 source.

Comment: Indeed. There is also nice explanation why there are those strange castings and magic numbers in the code.

Comment: @User1 As far as I understood, the OP asked exactly about this part.

Comment: So why the author of this code did write i = * (long *) &y; instead of i = (long) y; ?

Comment: @user2400925 because if you do `i = (long) y;` you will cast `float` to `long` and will modify a bit pattern, because a value of `y` will be rounded to the least closest integer. In the case ` i = * (long *) &y`, the bit pattern stays the same.

Comment: So *(int *) &i; this is a hack that allowes using reinterpret casting in C ?

Comment: And same as: reinterpret_cast<int>(&i); ?

Comment: In accordance to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast), you should either `reinterpret_cast<int>(i)` or `*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&i))`
I am not as good in `C++`, so can be a bit wrong.

Comment: Type punning in C++ is done by casting references. The equivalents of the two casts in the example are `i = reinterpret_cast<long&>(y);` and `y = reinterpret_cast<float&>(i);`. (See 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] p11).

Answer (score 2):

It all depends whether `i` is an object or a primitive type. If it is an object, `operator*` might be overloaded, giving an different overall meaning.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference, both assignments are essentially copying an `int`'s worth of bits from the memory storing `i` to the memory storing `k`.

Sometimes tricks like these are used when the types of the source and destination variables differ, but this is just plain `int` to `int`.

A sufficiently clever compiler ought to generate the exact same code for both versions, I think.

Comment: So why the author of this code did write i = * (long *) &y; instead of i = (long) y; ?