# Getting around the reinterpret cast limitation with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, reinterpret-cast

In c++11, a `constexpr` expression cannot contain reinterpret casts. So for instance, if one wanted to manipulate the bits in a floating point number, say to find the mantissa of the number:

```
constexpr unsigned int mantissa(float x) { 
    return ((*(unsigned int*)&x << 9) >> 9); 
};
```

The above code would fail to be `constexpr`.  In theory, I can't see how a reinterpret cast in this or similar cases can be any different from arithmetic operators, but the complier (and the standard) don't allow it.

Is there any clever way of getting around this limitation?

Comment: That's also not allowed in non-constexpr contexts. It's just plain undefined. But it can be made valid, and that still would not suffice in making it constexpr-valid, so the question is still valid.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in a `constexpr`, is `constexpr` the new feature to abuse?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - indeed. I'm trying to trying to explore the boundaries of some c++11 features, this isn't really a necessity.

Comment: @hvd - why is the code undefined? it's may not be portable, but it does work: http://ideone.com/Kh74Ub

Comment: @nbubis It violates strict aliasing.

Comment: I posted a question and it was linked to this one, can you please confirm if it 100% same, because my question was more specific to static member :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441338/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-a-pointer-member-in-c-11

Comment: One reason could be casting to `char*` to help with viewing an object's byte representation as a `char` array, @DavidRodríguez-dribeas.  I _believe_ that was legal for any type (outside of constant-expressions), at least, IIRC.

Comment: In C++20 `std::bit_cast` will help in some cases. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I can't see how a reinterpret cast in this or similar cases can be any
>   different from arithmetic operators

It isn't portable.

You are probably aware of the fact that your code causes undefined behavior, since you dereference a type punned pointer and thus break strict aliasing. Moreover, since C++14, operations that would invoke undefined behavior aren't even constant expressions anymore and should thus produce a compiler error.

What you are basically trying to do is alias the `float` object with an integral glvalue. The first step is to obtain that glvalue; the second  to perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

In C++14, the first step is impossible to accomplish in constant expressions. `reinterpret_cast` is explicitly forbidden. And casts to and from `void*`, like `static_cast<char const*>(static_cast<void const*>(&x))`, don't work either (N3797, [expr.const]/2*):

> — a conversion from type *cv* `void *` to a pointer-to-object type;

Keep in mind that a c-style cast like `(char*)` is reduced to either `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` whose limitations are listed above. `(unsigned*)&x` therefore reduces to `reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&x)` and doesn't work.

In C++11, the cast to `void const*` and then to `char const*` does not constitute a problem (according to standard; Clang still complains about the latter). The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is one nonetheless:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to 
> — a
>   glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile
>   const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a
>   constant expression, or 
> — a glvalue of literal type that refers to a
>   non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers to a
>   sub-object of such an object, or 
> — a glvalue of literal type that
>   refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not
>   ended, initialized with a constant expression;

The first two bullets can't apply here; Neither has any `char`/`unsigned`/etc. object been initialized precedingly, nor did we define any such object with `constexpr`.

The third bullet doesn't apply either. If we write

```
char ch = *(char const*)(void const*)&x;
```

we don't create a `char` object in the initializer. We access the stored value of `x` through a glvalue of type `char`, and use that value to initialize `ch`.

Therefore I'd say that such aliasing isn't possible in constant expressions. You may get around this in some implementations with relaxed rules.

---

* The paragraph is a list that starts with something like

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless [...]

<sub>(The text differs from N3337 to N3797.)</sub>

Answer (score 13):

Your particular example of getting a mantissa of a `float` number is actually quite simple to implement for *numbers* without type punning at all, and thus implement it in a `constexpr` fashion. The only problem would be when you want to hack on NaNs.

Since you already rely on `float` being the `binary32` from IEEE 754, we can assume the same, but in another way — to present results. See the following code:

```
#include <limits>
constexpr float abs(float x) { return x<0 ? -x : x; }

constexpr int exponent(float x)
{
    return abs(x)>=2 ? exponent(x/2)+1 :
           abs(x)<1  ? exponent(x*2)-1 : 0;
}

constexpr float scalbn(float value, int exponent)
{
    return exponent==0 ? value : exponent>0 ? scalbn(value*2,exponent-1) :
                                              scalbn(value/2,exponent+1);
}

constexpr unsigned mantissa(float x)
{
    return abs(x)<std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() ?
                // remove hidden 1 and bias the exponent to get integer
                scalbn(scalbn(abs(x),-exponent(x))-1,23) : 0;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    constexpr float x=-235.23526f;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    // Show non-constexpr result to compare with
    unsigned val; std::memcpy(&val,&x,sizeof val);
    std::cout << std::setw(8) << (val&0x7fffff) << "\n";
    // Now the sought-for constexpr result
    constexpr auto constexprMantissa=mantissa(x);
    std::cout << std::setw(8) << constexprMantissa << "\n";
}
```

See [its live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/868f5a07dd65ccb6).

Answer (score 9):

Starting with C++20 there's a standard library solution: [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (supported in GCC since GCC 11). Here's an example of using it:

```
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr float x=-235.23526f;
    constexpr auto integer=std::bit_cast<std::uint32_t>(x);
    constexpr auto mantissa=integer&0x7fffff;
    static_assert(mantissa==0x6b3c3a);
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(8) << mantissa << "\n";
}
```

See [its live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b6dc4393423cec0).