# error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, reinterpret-cast, gcc6

The following code fails to compile with GCC 6 and 32bit-mode (on a amd64 host).

```
class foo {
  static constexpr const char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(0xff);
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
g++ -m32 test.cc
```

Error message is:

```
test.cc:2:38: error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer
   static constexpr const char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(0xff);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It works with older compilers (GCC 4.9). It also works as inline definition (not as static member variable) or compiled in 64 bit mode.

Is there a way to get it working with GCC 6?

Comment: Can you alter the constant to add the size suffix? Maybe that'd help.

Comment: Related to [getting-around-the-reinterpret-cast-limitation-with-constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200827/getting-around-the-reinterpret-cast-limitation-with-constexpr)

Comment: Why do you think you need `reinterpret_cast` rather than `static_cast`?

Comment: @Jarod42 And GCC enforces this only in 32 bit mode?

Comment: @gerion: it should also be invalid in 64bit mode... Maybe the check is done according to (possible) `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` and so is not caught in 64bits mode..