# Is it possible to represent type float as an array of bytes in a constexpr context? (c++20)

Tags: c++, constexpr

bit operations - not for float,

union - reading an inactive member in a constant context is not allowed

```
constexpr auto Serialize(float x)
{
    // ?
}
int main()
{
    constexpr float a = 1.33;
    constexpr std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(float)> buffer = Serialize(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615663/817643

Comment: Thanks StoryTeller and Red.Wave. I didn't know about this feature. That's what I need. Hopefully this is a portable solution as long as the types are the same size.

Comment: It looks like the std::bit_cast is using some kind of built-in functionality:

  return __builtin_bit_cast(_To, __from);