# Using reinterpret_cast to check inheritance at compile time

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

Regarding this question: [When to use reinterpret_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast)

I found sth. like this:

```
template<typename T> bool addModuleFactoryToViewingFactory(ViewingPackage::ViewingFactory* pViewingFactory)
{
 static_cast<ModuleFactory*>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(0)); // Inheritance compile time check

  ...
}
```

Is this a good way to check whether `T` can be casted to `ModuleFactory` at compile time?
I mean, to check if the programmer put valid stuff into the `<>`of `addModuleFactoryToViewingFactory<T>(...)`
Is this okay, good or maybe the only way?

Greetings

Comment: yes. its not wrong... but is this a good way or the only one maybe?

Comment: It is probably not that good, remember static_cast is valid both ways, and reinterpret_cast is completely unwarranted here (you need another static_cast instead).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't need to be solved. Since C++11, we have Type Traits that allow us to check things like this explicitly in Template Metaprogramming.

For example, is_base_of

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: This question is *not* tagged as c++11.

Comment: Maybe C++11 can do better, but what if I am not allowed to use the new features of C++11?

Comment: If he is restricted to C++03, there's always BOOST.

Comment: I can actually give some guarantee that the Boost implementation will work, if that's what you mean. Like how would that code you post behave if your example you had non public inheritance or an ambiguous base class?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. The base class is ModuleFactory. I read the code like this: cast sth. to T* to check with static_cast if T* is somewhere in the inheritance 'tree' of ModuleFactory. If the base class `ModuleFactory`is sth. else the the code wouöd check if T* is type of 'sth. else' ?! Maybe its better to read if one would write sth. like this: `T* p; static_cast<ModuleFactory>(p)`. I think this should be the same nut without a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @MartinR.: You need to initialize `p`, and you probably just want `ModuleFactory *q=p;` to control the direction of the inheritance.