# Virtual functions and cast to void and back

Tags: c++, virtual, void, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Currently I am working with a legacy c++ code base. In this codebase pointer to objects are converted to void-pointers and then stored in a c-library.
Consider the following code:

```
class interface {
public:
  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "Interface" << std::endl;}
  virtual ~interface(){};
};

class debug_interface: public interface {
public:
  virtual void foo() {
   std::cout << "Debug Interface" << std::endl;}
};
```

The objects `interface` and `debug_interface` are allocated on the heap and the address is stored to a void pointer. At some point the pointers are retrieved and then casted back to the base-class `interface`. Then the virtual function call is invoked. See

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    void *handle = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new interface());
    void *debug_handle = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new debug_interface());

   //void *handle = new interface();
   //void *debug_handle = new debug_interface();

   interface *foo1 = reinterpret_cast<interface*>(handle);
   interface *foo2 = reinterpret_cast<interface*>(debug_handle);

   //interface *foo1 = static_cast<interface*>(handle);
   //interface *foo2 = static_cast<interface*>(debug_handle);

   foo1->foo();
   foo2->foo();

   return 0;
}
```

First of all I don't understand, why reinterpret_cast is used. As far as I know, pointer-to-objects can be implicitly converted to void*. Furthermore, to make this cast explicit, a static_cast would be enough, right?
But the more important question: Is it really save to cast the pointer debug_handle to interface* ( not to debug_interface*) and invoke the virtual call?  According to the c++-standard, (5.2.10) this is undefined behavior:

> A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer
>   to a different object type.69 When a prvalue v of type “pointer
>   to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is
>   static_cast(static_cast(v)) if both T1 and T2
>   are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of
>   T2 are no stricter than those of T1. Converting a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields
>   the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspecified.

The conversion from `handle` to `foo1` should be ok, but I can again use a static_cast?

**Edit**
My example source code was wrong. debug_interface is a derived class of interface.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is just a more explicit way of saying you want to cast it to a pointer.  You *could* use a c-style cast and perhaps incur a warning depending on the compiler.  If you're explicit you're telling the compiler you intended to interpret the value as a pointer rather than having done it by mistake.

Comment: you could be interested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/573345/2412846. It basically says it is safe.

Comment: Thanks, i read it. But I am still unsure aboute my second question. Am I just overly cautious or is this just dangerous?

Comment: "Safe" is not a very precise word. Will it work with your compiler? Probably. Is it standard-confirming? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** *This first part was written when the two interfaces were not related by inheritance.*

The undefined behaviour actually happens here:

```
   foo2->foo();
```

Here, you are using the `interface` API on a pointer to an object that is **not** implementing this API.
The fact that both `interface` and `debug_interface` happen to implement the `foo()` member as their first method does not change anything: those classes are not related by inheritance, so they are not compatible.

The extract you are citing treats about cases where the **conversion** itself is allowed. In your case, my understanding is that you can actually convert a pointer to `debug_interface` to a pointer to `interface`: yet, the only safe thing you can now do with you pointer to interface is to convert it back to a `debug_interface` pointer: using it to access `interface` members is unsafe.

---

**EDIT:** If `debug_interface` publicly derives from `interface`, this is a different problem.

In this case, it would be totally safe to cast from `debug_interface*` to `interface*`: the *derived-to-base* conversion can even be applied implicitly by the compiler.
Yet to be safe, this cast must be done **directly**, through either:

- a `static_cast`
- a `dynamic_cast` (which would introduce runtime check, being overkill for an upcast).

Doing it through two `reinterpret_cast` is an undefined behaviour: it is likely to work for single inheritance (on some compilers), but it is absolutely not guaranteed by the standard.
Doing it through two `static_cast` would also be an undefined behaviour. The standard guarantees that (emphasis mine):

> A value of type pointer to object converted to “pointer to cv void” and back to the **original pointer** type will have its original value.

In your example, you are not converting back to the original pointer, but to another pointer type: the standard is not giving you any guarantee about the value you will get.

### Possible solution

Knowing that:

1. It is safe to directly convert from `debug_interface` to `interface`
2. It is safe to convert from a pointer to object type to `void *` then back to pointer to the same object type.

You could assemble that to get a standard guaranteed solution:

```
// Safe, see point #1.
// The new expression returns a debug_interface* and static_cast applies a derived-to-base conversion.
interface *debug_handle_interim = static_cast<interface*>(new debug_interface());

// Convert a interface* to void* then back to interface*, see #2
void *type_erased = static_cast<void*>(debug_handle_interim);
interface *debug_handle_back = static_cast<interface*>(type_erased);
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. But it is a mistake in my example source. debug_interface is a derived class of interface.

Comment: @IcePic  Thank you for the comment, this changes a lot of things now ; )

Comment: @IcePic Edit your question to accurately reflect the inheritance relationship.

Comment: @Ad N: Thanks for the edit. How about the case, when debug_interface* is casted to void* and then back to interface*?

Comment: @IcePic It is undefined behaviour (cf. "*Doing it though two `reinterpret_cast`...*"). I will clarify that a bit.

Comment: Thanks again for your clarification. I got it now. There is a small error in your work around. Can you remove the new static_cast<void*>(new debug_handle_interim)? I can't edit your post.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is undefined. When you cast back a `void*` you should use always the original pointer type. And you should use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`.

So your code could be safely written as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    void *handle = new interface();
    void *debug_handle = static_cast<interface*>(new debug_interface());

    //Beware! This would be wrong:
    //void *debug_handle = new debug_interface();

   interface *foo1 = static_cast<interface*>(handle);
   interface *foo2 = static_cast<interface*>(debug_handle);

   foo1->foo();
   foo2->foo();

   return 0;
}
```

And indeed if you happen to have a class such as:

```
class weird_interface : something, public interface
{ /* */};
```

And then write:

```
weird_interface *a = new weird_interface();
interface *b = static_cast<interface*>(static_cast<void*>(a));
interface *c = a;
static_assert(b == c, "");
```

You'll see why the UB.

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed by the standard. The correct way to store the pointer would be:

```
interface* tmp = new debug_interface;
void* handle = reinterpret_cast<void*>(tmp);
```

You can of course do it in one line:

```
void* handle = reinterpret_cast<void*>(
    static_cast<interface*>(new debug_interface));
```

but this is too unwieldy and error-prone to my taste.

The standard allows you to cast a pointer to `void*` and back, but you have to cast it back to the exact same pointer type you've started with. Pointer to a base class is no substitute.

Your code has a good chance to crash and burn if you make `debug_interface` use multiple or virtual inheritance, but even with plain single inhetitance it's not conforming.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, and this code typically breaks for the second interface of a class.