# Casting void* to char*

Tags: c++, casting, char, void

## What is the best/safest way to cast void* to char* in c++?

static_cast or reinterpret_cast?

```
void I2C::Read(void* buffer, DWORD address, UINT size) 
{
    if (_isDeviceAvailable)
    {
        _iicInstance.seekg(address, std::ios_base::beg);
        _iicInstance.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer), size);
        Gpio::SVSet();
    }
```

}

Comment: There *is* no `PVOID` or `PCHAR` in C++. Perhaps you meant to tag this question with a specific implementation tag? :-)

Comment: `void*` and `char*` will be the same size, so all you have to do is cast it.

Comment: So its no matter what cast to use?

Comment: In this particular case, the two casts do the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static_cast` would be the choice here. Using `static_cast` to and from a `void*` preserves the adress, see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573345/5064389) also explains why not to use `reinterpret_cast` in similar situations.

Comment: Ty, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast/573345#573345) is great explanation, better than msdn.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the question. I have closed this thread based on that. BTW, your answer is true, but the reasoning is wrong. With C++11, both `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` do the same thing. However, one should use `static_cast` wherever possible on `reinterpret_cast`. Usually the latter is used, when casting between altogether different types; e.g. `long` to `X*`. IMO, below is the ugliness index of casts (least to most): `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, *"C-style cast"*.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification. Should I edit my answer into something more appropriate?