# Obtaining an int from a void pointer which points to a short

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion, void-pointers

I have a return value from a library which is a void pointer. I know that it points to a short int; I try to obtain the int value in the following way (replacing the function call with a simple assignment to a `void *`):

```
short n = 1;
void* s = &n;
int k = *(int*)s;
```

I try to cast a void pointer that points to an address in which there is a short and I try to cast the pointer to point to an int and when I do so the output becomes a rubbish value. While I understand why it's behaving like that I don't know if there's a solution to this.

Comment: The solution is to not do the cast.

Comment: `int k = *(short*)s`?

Comment: @juanchopanza how do you mean?

Comment: I have a problem in which something like this arises

Comment: @airomyst I mean don't do this cast: `(int*)s`.

Comment: Casting *anything* to a `void*` (and back) is often the result of bad design (as you loose all type information and safety). Why do you need to do this?

Comment: \*(int\*)s is trying to dereference a 4-byte address but the variable n occupies only 2-bytes so it's not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see your point yes. but as I said I have a similar problem in which I kinda need to do this. or do you mean I can't get away with it?

Comment: The size of a `short` and `int` are different and result in a bad conversion @UnholySheep is right `void*` are bad, but if you use it make sure it is done correctly.

Comment: When you cast an int pointer from a short, it will pick up two more bytes, (on most systems), as part of the value that have nothing to do with the original short. Hence, you get a garbage value. The compiler won't 'fix' this for you as it will simply do what you ask of it.

Comment: I have a function that returns a void pointer and I would need to cast the value accordingly.

Comment: Is that function from an external library/API you cannot modify? If yes then it needs to somehow give you information about what data type this pointer is pointing to, a `void*` itself does not hold any information about that

Comment: @airomyst you can only cast it back to it's original type not whatever type you would like it to be.  Any other cast to an unrelated type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes that is the case.

Comment: @RichardCritten I understand it is an undefined behavior I was asking if I can get around it and to solve my problem.

Comment: airomyst, is the return from this function documented? Sounds like it may be...

Comment: The whole discussion above reminds me of an old joke and patient comes to see a doctor and says 'Doctor, it hurts me very much when I do this, what can you advise?', - and stretches his body in a very twisted way. To that doctor replies: 'I advise you not to do that.'

Comment: @SergeyA Well, I might have a different view. anyway, I got what I needed. thanks.

Comment: @airomyst -- That API function is useless if the documentation doesn't tell you what the real type is behind that `void *`.

Comment: I changed the question to include what you added in your comments (which you should do yourself next time ;-) ). Feel free to revert if you don't like it. You may also want to edit in the actual function call and (if it's not too complicated) the original function declaration from a header. Generally you get the best answers if you keep as close to the original problem as possible.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem you are dealing with truly deals with `short` and `int`, you can simply avoid the pointer and use:

```
short n = 1;
int k = n;
```

If the object types you are dealing with are different, then the solution will depend on what those types are.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

In a comment, you said,

> I have a function that returns a void pointer and I would need to cast the value accordingly.

If you know that the function returns a `void*` that truly points to a `short` object, then, your best bet is:

```
 void* ptr = function_returning_ptr();
 short* sptr = reinterpret_cast<short*>(ptr);
 int k = *sptr;
```

The last line work since `*sptr` evaluates to a `short` and the conversion of a `short` to an `int` is a valid operation. On the other hand,

```
 int k = *(int*)sptr;
```

does not work since conversion of `short*` to an `int*` is not a valid operation.

Comment: You could elaborate that the conversion short -> int is legit and fairly commonplace, while the conversion short* -> int* is neither.

Comment: Can you explain why *static_cast* is not used in place of *reinterpret_cast*? This post suggests that a *static_cast* should generally be preferred in  void* conversions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast

Comment: @dsp_user, I didn't draw the same conclusion from the linked post as you did. Either seems to be a good option to convert between pointers.

Comment: Well, even a C-style cast will do though some people object to using C-style conversions in C++. I don't ;)

Comment: @dsp_user, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx.

Comment: @SergeyA Why would this code not compile with `static_cast`?

Comment: Yes, when objects (classes) are involved *static_cast* does provide compile-time type checks.

Comment: @user3366592 because I was wrong, I somehow misread the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is subject to undefined behavior, as it violates the so-called strict aliasing rules. Without going into too much detail and simplifying a bit, the rule states that you can not access an object of type X though a pointer to type Z unless types X and Z are related. There is a special exception for char pointer, but it doesn't apply here.

In your example, `short` and `int` are not related types, and as such, accessing one through pointer to another is not allowed.

Comment: While all you say is true (though it's just repeating comments), it does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I am not sure what is OP's problem to begin with.

Comment: He elaborated in the comments; I edited the question accordingly because I can imagine that it's not obvious that `(int)some_short`  is valid while `(int *) some_short_ptr`  is not. After understanding the OP's issue the question seemed more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a short is only 16 bits the size of a int is 32 bits ( in most cases not always) this means that you are tricking the computer into thinking that your pointer to a short is actually pointing to an integer. This causes it to read more memory that it should and is reading garbage memory. If you cast s to a pointer to a short then deference it it will work.

```
   short n = 1;
   void* s = &n;
   int k = *(short*)s;
```

Comment: `short` is definitely not 8 bits, that would violate the C++ standard (which states that `short` is *at least* 16 bits)

Comment: `short` is **at least** 16 bits, and `int` is **at least** 16 bits. They may well be the same size, and on many systems they are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 byte shorts and 4 byte ints, There's 3 problems with casting pointers in your method.

First off, the 4 byte int will necessarily pick up some garbage memory when using the short's pointer.  If you're *lucky* the 2 bytes after `short n` will be 0.

Second, the 4 byte int may not be properly aligned.  Basically, the memory address of a 4 byte `int` has to be a multiple of 4, or else you risk bus errors.  Your 2 byte `short` is not guaranteed to be properly aligned.

Finally, you have a big-endian/little-endian dependency.  You can't turn a big-endian short into a little-endian int by just tacking on some 0's at the end.

In the very fortunate circumstance that the bytes following the `short` are 0, AND the `short` is integer aligned, AND the system uses little-endian representation, then such a cast will probably work.  It would be terrible, but it would (probably) work.

---

The proper solution is to use the original type and let the compiler cast.  Instead of `int k = *(int*)s;`, you need to use `int k = *(short *)s;`