# Converting a vector to structure in Cpp

Tags: c++, vector

How do I convert a `std::vector<uint8_t>` to my custom defined structure?

For example I have

```
struct abc
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
};
```

Does `reinterpret_cast` works in this?

I am a beginner in C++, but have good knowledge in C.

Comment: You cannot convert a `std::vector` to a custom defined structure without introducing more or less [U.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) At least, you should [edit] and specify `std::vector` of what. (Though, I see few chances for an exception from the first sentence.)

Comment: You have to implement a conversion function. For example: `abc from_vector(std::vector<char> vec) { return abc{vec.at(0), vec.at(1), vec.at(2)}; }`

Comment: At best, you could do a `reinterprete_cast` of `std::vector<uint8_t>::data()`. `data()` provides the pointer to raw-data in `std::vector` which is granted to be contiguous. But, I still would be afraid about [U.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) although there are some special exceptions for `char*` and `unsigned char*` (to which `std::uint8_t` is probably an alias) in the standard.

Comment: Concerning `reinterprete_cast`, I found a nice Q/A [SO: When to use reinterpret_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573294/7478597).

Comment: There are some good answers here in the comments section

Comment: What do the `uint8_t`s come from and what do they represent? What do you expect the value `255` to become when converted to `char`? `-1`? `-127`? `-128`? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not in a type safe and supported way. What you can do is roll your own copy method. In your case it would be as simple as `memcpy(vec.data(), &struct, sizeof(struct))` assuming the vector is a direct translation (i.e 3 elements).

Comment: Only if the members are tightly packed and start at the start of the class

Comment: Ya, that's what I meant with the ``assuming the vector is a direct translation`` comment. The main point I was making in any case was that it will need a custom implementation.

Comment: with your approach possibly you are collecting out of bound memory access