# Int to ASCII char and char to ASCII number | C++

Tags: c++, ascii

**I must write short script which will change int to ASCII char and char to ASCII int. But i don't know how. I wrote this short code but something is wrong. I'm programming for half-year.** Can someone write it working? It is my first time to use functions in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
char toChar(int n) {
return n + '0';
}
int toInt(char c) {
return c - '0';
}
int main()
{
int number;
cout << "Int: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "ASCII: " << static_cast<char>(number);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What's the current output and what is the expected output? How are you running the program (which number you give it as input)? See also [example].

Comment: Suppose you have `int x = 1;` you can then interpret that as ascii `1`, or you can get the ascii code for the character `'1'`. To be sure what you want you should include input, output and expected output

Comment: If you have an error with `_getch` don't use `_getch`! Use `getch` instead

Comment: @Dock ok i will try this

Comment: i edited it but i don't know how to use this functions toChar and toInt

Comment: maybe someone can write it working? it is my first time to use functions in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also use printf, so you don't need to create other function for converting the number.

```
int i = 64;
char c = 'a';

printf("number to ascii corresponding to %d is %c\n", i, i);
printf("ascii to number corresponding to %c is %d\n", c, c);
```

the output is gonna be

```
number to ascii corresponding to 64 is A
ascii to number corresponding to a is 97
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank You very much Guys, I have done it with shorter and working code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int a=68;
cout<<char(a);
char c='D';
cout<<int(c);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char toChar(int n)
{
    if (n > 127 || n < 0)
        return 0;
    return (char)n;
}

int toInt(char c)
{
    return (int)c;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 97;
    cout << "char corresponding to number " << number << " is '" <<  toChar(number) << "'\n";

    char car='H';
    cout << "number corresponding to char '" << car << "' is " << toInt(car) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
char corresponding to number 97 is 'a'
number corresponding to char 'H' is 72'
```

---

Originally I thought you were just looking to convert the number:
You can simply add and substract '0', to char and from char:

```c
char toChar(int n) {
    return n + '0';
}
```

```c
int toInt(char c) {
    return c - '0';
}
```

If you just want to [cast the type, read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast)

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: above the main function

Comment: @KacperPodsiadło • why did you put `_getch` in the code in the first place?

Comment: @KacperPodsiadło if you get the error for `_getch` after adding thsoe two function it should have been there already before. You should have explained in your question what is wrong and include the error message.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL i still don't know what to do, can you write it but working or help one more time?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could start with the code below. If this is incomplete, could you please complete your question with test cases?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

char toChar(int n)
{   //you should test here the number shall be ranging from 0 to 127
    return (char)n;
}

int toInt(char c)
{
    return (int)c;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 97;
    cout << "number to ascii corresponding to  " << number << " is " <<(char)number << " or " << toChar(number) <<endl;

    char car='H';
    cout << "ascii to number corresponding to " << car << " is " << (int)car << " or " << toInt(car) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
number to ascii corresponding to  97 is a or a
ascii to number corresponding to H is 72 or 72
```